# pcscd does not exist in /usr/sbin

Tags: macos

I'm trying to install a USB certificate token on OS X Yosemite 10.10.1 (14B25) and the guides tell me to check that a certain daemon named pcscd is running and to start from `/usr/sbin/pcscd` if not.

Here a link to the guide: http://wiki.infonotary.com/wiki/Installation_of_smart_card_reader_and_smart_card_drivers_in_Mac_OS_X#Manually_running_and_stopping_pcscd

However it does not exist. 
I execute:

```
sh-3.2# cd /usr/sbin
sh-3.2# ls -la |grep pcscd
sh-3.2#
```

and as visible there is no file named `pcscd`.

There is also no process called `pcscd` when running

```
ps -a -u root
```

Should I install some additional package for this one?

Comment: I think you need to install this https://smartcardservices.macosforge.org/

Comment: Doesn't help - the file is still missing. It's very odd since I got pcsctest for example but not the daemon executable.

Comment: Which guides show this?

Comment: added a link to it

Answer (score 1):

I managed to resolve this on my own.

Looks like the smartcard was actually working even if the pcscd executable is not present. Most probably the functionality was integrated into another service.